# What am I missing? Getting data from a JSON API URL to display on bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to teach myself javascript and having trouble converting the JSON from this link https://www2.shapeshift.io/crowdsales to display on a bootstrap page using javascript, HTML, and CSS. I can't seem to get it working and I'm not sure why, can someone please help?

**Here is the javascript:**

```
$.get( "http://www2.shapeshift.io/crowdsales", function( data ) {
    var sold = data['sold.toFixed(2)'];
    var left = data['remaining'];
    var total = sold + left;
    var ratebtc = data['rateT'];
    var percent = sold/total * 100;
    var raised = data.toFixed(2) + 'BTC';
    var percentsold = data.toFixed(2) + '%';
    var orders = data['backers'];
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', percentsold);
    $('.percentage-label').html( percentsold + " \(" + sold + " sold out of " + total + " \)");
    $('.ratebtc').html( ratebtc );
    $('.orders').html( orders);
    $('.raised').html( raised);
});
```

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<div class="shapeshift">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-5 object-non-visible"
        data-animation-effect="fadeIn">
            <div class="orders"></div>

            <div class="raised"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="banner-buynow">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-5 object-non-visible"
        data-animation-effect="fadeIn">
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=
            "opentac();">Buy Now<br>

            <div class="ratebtc"></div></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar active progress-bar-striped" style=
        "width:50%">
            <div class="percentage-label"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Here is the CSS**

```
}
.banner-buynow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
.shapeshift {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
.progress {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: did you check the code run with any error in console? I got this `Uncaught TypeError: data.toFixed is not a function`. maybe you can put your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ and let others can easily help you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.get( "http://www2.shapeshift.io/crowdsales", function( data ) {
  
   var sold = parseFloat(data['sold']).toFixed(2);//problem
    var left = data['remaining'];
    var total = parseFloat(sold + left).toFixed(2);//problem
    var ratebtc = data['rateT'];
    var percent = sold/total * 100;
    var raised = parseFloat(data['raised']).toFixed(2) + 'BTC';//problem
    var percentsold = parseFloat(data['sold']).toFixed(2) + '%';//problem
    var orders = data['backers'];
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', percentsold);
    $('.percentage-label').html( percentsold + " \(" + sold + " sold out of " + total + " \)");
    $('.ratebtc').html( ratebtc );
    $('.orders').html( orders);
    $('.raised').html( raised);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shapeshift">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-5 object-non-visible"
        data-animation-effect="fadeIn">
            <div class="orders"></div>

            <div class="raised"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="banner-buynow">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-5 object-non-visible"
        data-animation-effect="fadeIn">
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=
            "opentac();">Buy Now<br>

            <div class="ratebtc"></div></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar active progress-bar-striped" style=
        "width:50%">
            <div class="percentage-label"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Problems:

1. You need to use the data which are present in json `var raised = data.toFixed(2) + 'BTC';
   var percentsold = data.toFixed(2) + '%';` seems useless for me. because data is an object.
2. toFixed() will only work with floats.

try putting this code and check.

Answer (score 0):

To get json response from URL use `$.getJSON`

```js
var url = "https://www2.shapeshift.io/crowdsales";

$.getJSON(url , function (json) {

    var status= json.status;
    console.log(status);

});
```

```html
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```